# How to display clear background image on Android Wear notification?

Tags: wear-os

As far as I can work out, there are two ways to set the background image for a notification in Android Wear. For the record, both start with:

```
   Bitmap bitmap;
   Notification.Builder bob = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
```

...and so on to set up the notification. Also assume that `bitmap` has been initialized to an appropriately-sized image (though that's another issue).

Method 1:

```
   bob.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
```

This works, but AFAICT `bitmap` is always blurred-out in the background of the notification, regardless of its size.

Method 2:

```
   bob.setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap));
```

This clears up the bitmap, but has the unfortunate side effect of inserting an extra "page" on the wearable, a page that is blank except for the bitmap. I suppose the thinking here is that you're trying to show the image to the user - but I'm not, I just want a non-blurry background.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use `setBackground(Bitmap)` method from `WearableExtender` instead of `setLargeIcon(Bitmap)`. It will set the background bitmap that won't be blurred.

```
Notification.Builder wearableBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    ...
    .extend(new WearableExtender().setBackground(bitmap));
```

Comment: Perfect! For future reference, if you *also* want to use `setLargeIcon()`, this seems to disable it... but you can get equivalent functionality by calling `WearableExtender.setContentIcon()` instead.

Comment: yes, `setBackground()` will replace the "blurry" `setLargeIcon()` background on Wearable. So if your `setLargeIcon()` is some contact image or other such image - just use `setBackground` and no need to add anything more. But if you have some informative icon that describes your content - you can add it in `setContentIcon`:) Bonus: If you want to make your notification clickable on Android Wear, you can assign an action to it. The `setContentAction(int)` method on `WearableExtender` will "merge" given action into card + the icon of this action will be shown in place of contentIcon.

Comment: `setBackground()` is still blurry, just less so. The image is cropped to square then scaled down to 400x400 if it's bigger than that, then stretched to stick out each side of the screen by 20% of the screen size. The math means blurry background images for watches with screens bigger than 285x285.