# Background image for android wear notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I want to set background image for Android Wear notification. What should be the size of the image?

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/design/wear/style.html] check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution for square watch faces as of right now is 280x280, whereas the circular watch face has a resolution of 320x320 (although some of this will be cut off, obviously).

However, Android Wear implements a sort of parallax scrolling by default for larger images, so it can handle larger images with great ease, and it is even recommended that you do so ([see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841329/how-to-display-clear-background-image-on-android-wear-notification/24842082#24842082)). So you really shouldn't worry about the size of the image, unless you were trying to create a static, full-screen image with specific areas of interaction as a substitute for custom UI elements (which you can do, I might add, although Google recommends you have only one area of interaction per screen on the watch to keep things simple).

If you want to see a good example of multiple images being used for backgrounds with parallax scrolling, I recommend you check out the GridViewPager sample project, which can be found in the SDK samples in the wearable subfolder for API level 20.

Comment: In my current tests, I have the parallax scrolling even if I use a 400x400 image, which is actually annoying (my notification has only one page, so this is useless).  I also tried with a 320x320 image, which is the resolution of my device: when doing that the image is scaled up :(

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) specifies that the background should be 400 x 400 if it should not use parallax scrolling and a size of  640x400 if it should support parallax scrolling.

The image should be put into the drawable-nodpi folder of your android app.

I couldn't make out a difference in the scrolling with different backgrounds. The bigger background is cropped to 400 x 400 and even if scrolling nothing outside the 400 x400 area is shown.

Answer (score 0):

In which use cases do you require parallax scrolling? I believe it only works in Notifications and GridViewPager.