# I can't see the background of my Android Wear Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os, wearables

my question is for I can't see the background in my Android Wear emulator, I declare .setBackgroung with a validated image but when I run the App and send me a notification the background does not show.

Any help?

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String TAG = "FIREBASE";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 001;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        enviarNotificacion(remoteMessage);
    }

    public void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("TOQUE_ANIMAL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri sonido = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_full_poke,
                        getString(R.string.texto_accion_toque), pendingIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender =
                new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                .setHintHideIcon(true)
                .setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.bk_androidwear_notification))
                .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificacion)
                .setContentTitle("Notificacion")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sonido)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .extend(wearableExtender.addAction(action))
                //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_full_poke, getString(R.string.texto_accion_toque), pendingIntent)
                ;

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificacion.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841329/how-to-display-clear-background-image-on-android-wear-notification). Try to use `setBackground(Bitmap)` method from `WearableExtender` instead of `setLargeIcon(Bitmap)`. You may also check this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/watchface/index.html#0) on how to create a watchface for Android Wear.

Additional reference to set background image for Android Wear notification: [Background image for android wear notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051681/background-image-for-android-wear-notification)

> The resolution for square watch faces as of right now is 280x280, whereas the circular watch face has a resolution of 320x320 (although some of this will be cut off, obviously).
>
> However, Android Wear implements a sort of parallax scrolling by default for larger images, so it can handle larger images with great ease, and it is even recommended that you do so ([see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841329/how-to-display-clear-background-image-on-android-wear-notification/24842082#24842082)). So you really shouldn't worry about the size of the image, unless you were trying to create a static, full-screen image with specific areas of interaction as a substitute for custom UI elements (which you can do, I might add, although Google recommends you have only one area of interaction per screen on the watch to keep things simple).
>
> If you want to see a good example of multiple images being used for backgrounds with parallax scrolling, I recommend you check out the GridViewPager sample project, which can be found in the SDK samples in the wearable subfolder for API level 20.

Hope this helps!