# Android Wear notification not showing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-notifications, wear-os

Hi I'm writing an Android Wear app that allows the user to control a music player from their watch. I'm trying to do it with a notification with two action buttons. Below is the code that creates/updates the notification when the currently playing song changes, it is from `OnDataChanged()` from the `WearableListenerService`. The data arrives on the emulator as expected and the notification builder is constructed correctly, as I can see it in the debugger. Also the final log line is executed and I can see it in logcat, however the notification is not created on the emulator. Also all other notifications from other apps on my phone show up on emulator!

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks James!

```
for (DataEvent event : events) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            if ("/playmusicremotedata".equals(path)) {
                // Get the data out of the event
                DataMapItem dataMapItem =
                        DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                final String songTitle = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString("songTitle");
                final String artist = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString("artist");
                final String album = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString("album");
                Asset asset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("albumArt");

                Bitmap albumArt = loadBitmapFromAsset(asset);

                PendingIntent skipForwardPendInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 8, new Intent("net.jamyspex.remoteforgoogleplaymusic.SKIP_FORWARD"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                PendingIntent playPausePendInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 7, new Intent("net.jamyspex.remoteforgoogleplaymusic.PLAY_PAUSE"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Notification.Action playPauseBut = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.play, "Pause/Play", playPausePendInt);
                Notification.Action nextBut = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.skip_forward, "Skip", skipForwardPendInt);

                // Create the ongoing notification
                Notification.Builder notificationBuilder =
                        new Notification.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle(songTitle)
                                .setContentText(artist + " - " + album)
                                .setLargeIcon(albumArt)
                                .setOngoing(true)
                                .addAction(playPauseBut)
                                .addAction(nextBut);

                // Build the notification and show it
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
                Log.i(TAG, "Should have created notification");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognized path: " + path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the question body I can guess that this code is being executed on `Android Wear` device (not from phone). But the last sentence from the question "Also all other notifications from other apps on my phone show up on emulator!" does comparing this to "other" notifications posted from phone. Can you specify this?:)

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga By other notifications i mean notifications from other apps like WhatsApp and Google Now.

Comment: But this code is invoked from watch, right?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga yeah ongoing notifications don't show on the watch unless you create them on the watch.

Comment: I know, that is why i'm asking:) I have tested your code (with minor change) and it works fine on my emulator. I have removed the line with `.setLargeIcon(albumArt)` because I don't have any asset to send and test it. So my test was without this line and it works fine. Test if it will work for you without setting `largeIcon`. Maybe the asset is corrupted and this preventing your notification to be displayed somehow?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I'm afraid its still not working for me! So, so annoying. I can see from the "Should have created notification" log message it executes with no errors, yet no notification appears. Worst thing is that the exact same code used to work and now it doesn't. The worst side of programming!

Comment: So I'm afraid that I cannot help you further:( Only one bonus tip: Do not use `setLargeIcon` to set background image on Android Wear - use `setBackground` method on `WearableExtender`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24842082/3827276. EDIT: One random idea: maybe you have your app muted on Android Wear? The "mute app" button appears in every ongoing notification displayed on Wear, maybe you have clicked it accidentally or something like that?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga Dude you are a hero I had muted it thanks so so so much, that would have driven me insane, feeling very stupid now!. Thanks for your help and that pointer on `setBackground`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the solution more visible to users who may be affected with the same issue - i'm posting this as an answer.

### REASON:

The reason was simple: **app was muted** (probably accidentally) on Android Wear device and this was preventing any notifications from appearing on watch.

While posting any ongoing notification from watch, there will be extra action added automatically. It is called "**Mute app**" and probably it was pressed in some point in time during development by accident.

Muted apps can be managed in the Android Wear companion app on Settings screen. This can be fairly hard to debug because any code is invoked without any error and there is also no logs in the LogCat about the fact that app is muted.

I hope that it will be helpful for other users that will search for the similar issue in the future:)

Comment: Is it possible to detect in code, that notifications for the app is muted?

Comment: @korovyansk I don't know any way to check that and I'm afraid that this is not possible.

Comment: Weird. Do you know suitable place to send feature requests for Wear SDK?

Comment: I think that it is similar to "Disable notifications" feature on phone. This feature exist for some time now and there is no way to detect that. I don't know why anyone would want to check that. That was basically created to stop spamming the user, if app would be able to detect that it could spam user to unblock it etc... But if you want you can submit an issue to android bug tracker with [Wear] tag: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: On watch user can click it randomly and for some cases it can absolutely break UX of wear app, so if we can check it, we can show activity with text that user need to unmute app to restore normal UX, in other case it will confuse user and we will not be able to advise.

Comment: For example my favorite Timer app, muting of notifications, completely break its UX. And here its big difference in timer UX on phone and wear, because on phone it based on activity with notification as extra bit of info, but on wear notification is the main part of timer standard ux

Comment: Go ahead and submit an issue with that:) Personally, instead of that approach I would prefer "more steps to Mute the app" solution. This will eliminate muting an app by accident. With that solution you know that if an app is muted - user wanted that and he is aware of it - so no need to check and notify it to him every time he launches the app.

Comment: More steps to mute the app, have no ideas how to combine it with ongoing notification, do you?

Comment: @korovyansk I mean that (in my opinion) it would be better if the Mute app action would require more steps (like confirmations, warning messages etc). This is not an action that will be used frequently and don't need to be one-click-and-done type action without any confirmation. This would require support from system but I think that would be better approach (for user) than allow developers to check the fact that app is muted or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and sent couple of hours trying to solve it.
In my case, I had the debug permanent notification (covering half the screen), and when my notification arrived to the watch, I couldn't see it.
**Only by swiping up all the notifications, I finally was able to see it, it was simply berried there.**